# Finish game loop and go to another activity Android 2.1

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-intent, android-activity

Please help me answer this challenge. I have been looking all over the internet and this board for the answer. I cant referr to anything that has been posted before anywhere on the internet. This question might be trivial to someone who knows whats he's doing in Android.

Basically what im trying to do is finish the game loop and go to a results page. When the game hits the if() for the end game. The animation stops but the intent is still on top of the screen.

How i create the intent:

```
package com.droidnova.android.tutorial2d;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Menu extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu);
    Button btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart);

 btnStart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Tutorial2D.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
        }});


}
}
```

How i create the panel:

```
package com.droidnova.android.tutorial2d;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
public class Tutorial2D extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(new Panel(this));
}
@Override
protected
 void onStop(){
    //finish();
    setContentView(R.layout.wynik);
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Wynik.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    //getParent();
    super.onStop();
}
protected void onPause(){
finish();
getParent();
super.onPause();
}}
```

Panel:

```
package com.droidnova.android.tutorial2d;

import java.util.*;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;


public class Panel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

public static float mWidth;
public static float mHeight;
boolean koniec=false;

public float ostatnix;
public float ostatniy;
public int testx,testy;
public static int c=1;
public int punkty;

public ViewThread mThread;
private ArrayList<Element> mElements = new ArrayList<Element>();
private int mElementNumber = 0;
private Bitmap tlo;

private Paint mPaint = new Paint();

public Panel(Context context) {
    super(context);
    getHolder().addCallback(this);
    mThread = new ViewThread(this);
    mPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    tlo = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.tlo);
}

public void doDraw(long elapsed, Canvas canvas) {//rysujemy!!
    if(!koniec){

    canvas.drawBitmap(tlo, 0, 0, null);
    synchronized (mElements) {
        for (Element element : mElements) {
            element.doDraw(canvas);
        }
        }
    }
    else{canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
    //canvas.draw
    };   

    }
//   Element znajdz = mElements.get(0);
//    canvas.drawText("FPS: " + Math.round(1000f / elapsed) + " Elements: " + mElementNumber +"X:  "+znajdz.x1+"Y:   "+znajdz.y1, 10, 10, mPaint);
//    canvas.drawText("Ostatni X:  "+ostatnix+"  Y:   "+ostatniy+" testx: "+testx+" testy: "+testy+" Punkty: "+punkty, 20, 20, mPaint);
//  }

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    mWidth = width;
    mHeight = height;
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    if (!mThread.isAlive()) {
        //c=0;
        mThread = new ViewThread(this);
        mThread.setRunning(true);
        mThread.start();
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    if (mThread.isAlive()) {

        mThread.setRunning(false);

    }
}

public void addelements(){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<1;i++){
        mElements.add(new Element(getResources(), (int) 100, (int) 100));
        mElementNumber = mElements.size();
    }
}
public void koniec(){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<mElements.size();i++){
        Element znajdz = mElements.get(i);
if(znajdz.y1>mHeight*0.9){
koniec=true;
```

Here i need to put some code that will go to results screen when this if() is true.
    }

```
    }
}    
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    synchronized (mElements) {  
 //       mElements.add(new Element(getResources(), (int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY()));
   //     mElementNumber = mElements.size();
ostatnix=(float) event.getX();
ostatniy=(float) event.getY();

int b;
for(b=0;b<mElements.size();b++){
        Element znajdz = mElements.get(b);
        testx=(int) znajdz.x1;testy=(int) znajdz.y1;
        if(znajdz.x1+5<event.getX()&&event.getX()<znajdz.x1+64&&
                znajdz.y1+5<event.getY()&&event.getY()<znajdz.y1+66 
                ){
            punkty++;
            mElements.remove(znajdz);
        }
};
(mElements.to(array));
            //array = list.toArray(EMPTY_STRING_ARRAY);
            mElements.trimToSize(); 
            mElementNumber = mElements.size();
            if(mElements.size()==0){        int i;
                for(i=0;i<c;i++){
                mElements.add(new Element(getResources(), (int) i, (int) i));
                mElementNumber = mElements.size();
                }
            c++;    
            }
    };

    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

public void animate(long elapsedTime) {
    synchronized (mElements) {
        for (Element element : mElements) {
            element.animate(elapsedTime);
        }
    }
}
}
```

I didn't want to ask here but im forced by my lack of knowledge on the topic and unability to find the answer :( Please help.

Answer (score 1):

See [`startActivity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivity%28android.content.Intent%29):

```
startActivity(new Intent(context, ResultsActivity.class));
```

Make sure you declare your results Activity to your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Comment: Context a=getContext();
a.getApplicationContext();
a.startActivity(new Intent(a, Wynik.class));
This is how i implemented it and now i cant use the buttons on the screen and the process just hangs for a few sec and then the button becomes active. Im green about how to handle the whole context thing. Btw ur answer was perfect i just need to know how to handle that context.

Comment: You don't need to include the `getApplicationContext` step, you can use any Context instance. I'm not sure why it would hang. You probably have some other processing active on the main thread that you need to stop before starting the new activity.

Comment: wow, nice! Thank you so much. I searched for hours and read a lot. Now everything runs perfectly.